# Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

Есть докер контейнер, в котором сервис, который сам раздаёт статику и он же бэкенд. 
Статика раздаётся по роуту http://192.168.0.101:8071/static/index.html это главная страница. По http://192.168.0.101:8071/static не раздаётся.

Как мне в Nginx засунуть в upstream несколько таких сервисов? Должно как-то очень просто быть, но сообразить не могу. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: сумбурно изложено: не понятно что хотите? прокси-балансировщик? разные беки на одном хосте но на разных URI? раздавать и статику, и дергать бек? ничего не понятно

Comment: меня ставит в тупик тот факт, что статику раздаёт не nginx.

мне нужен nginx в нём upstream, в upstream нужно вписать несколько этих сервисов. каждый сервис сам по себе раздаёт и статику и бэкенд.

роуты доступные в сервисе

**ROUTER = MapRouter([
    ('/json-rpc/web/$', '%s.web.WebApiService' % PROJECT_NAME),
    ('/json-rpc/mobile/$', '%s.mobile.MobileApiService' % PROJECT_NAME),
    ('/files/', '%s.mobile.HttpService' % PROJECT_NAME),
    ('/static/[0]', FileSystemPublisher('/static', os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')))
])**

Answer (score 2):

Не уверен, что точно Вас понял, но в NginX статику часто выделяют так, просто прописав префикс URI и соответствующий путь на диске:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.your_website.com;

    # Статика
    location /static/ {
        root /путь/до/статических/файлов/;
    }

    # Обратный прокси на локальный порт 8888
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Также можно настроить несколько путей:

```
    location /static/ {
        root /путь/до/статических/файлов/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /другой/путь/;
    }
```

В том числе по конкретным файлам или более сложным правилам, [см. документацию](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).